# Text reading and string inputting program

Tags: c#, console, stream

The Main program. This program pulls from a .txt document with two separate strings, and outputs a  .cs program that will display those two string via console when run. It uses a structure.txt file for the code it inputs the strings into.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        //structure.txt contains the program we will enter our values into.
        String filePath = "Structure.txt";

        WriteToFile(filePath);



    }

    public static void WriteToFile(string filePath)
    {
        //create a string array to gather our text file information.

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        StreamReader info = new StreamReader("Structure.txt");

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Hello.cs", true);
        String temp = String.Empty;

        while (!info.EndOfStream)
        {
            String tempstring = String.Empty;
            tempstring = reader.ReadLine();

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {

                temp = reader.ReadLine();
                writer.WriteLine(temp);
                if (temp == "//break")
                {
                    writer.WriteLine($"String1 = {tempstring}");

                }
                else if (temp == "//break 2") {
                    writer.WriteLine($"String2 = {tempstring}");
                }

            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        info.Close();


        writer.Close();
    }

}
}
```

structure.txt is just a basic program that prints the two strings gathered from the main program unto the console.

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
class Hello 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
//break

//break 2

    Console.WriteLine(string1);

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    Console.WriteLine(string2);
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
//end
}
```

This program runs, but I am wanting to improve the code and increase its efficiency.

Comment: Hello, welcome on Code Review. Can you explaine the difference between `while (!info.EndOfStream)` and `while (!reader.EndOfStream)` please?

Comment: I have a hard believing that `hello.cs` compiles, since the data being written to the file isn't in proper `C#` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you even have tested this program:

This:

> ```
>   while (!info.EndOfStream)
>   {
>     String tempstring = String.Empty;
>     tempstring = reader.ReadLine();
>
>     while (!reader.EndOfStream)
>     {
> ```

will run forever because `info` is never read from and will never reach EOS.

---

In the context this:

> ```
>    while (!info.EndOfStream)    {
>      String tempstring = String.Empty;
>      tempstring = reader.ReadLine();
> ```

is not understandable. Do you have the `tempstring` that is going to be written instead of the placeholders in the top of the structure.txt-file?

You open the same file twice:

> ```
> public static void WriteToFile(string filePath)
> {
>   //create a string array to gather our text file information.
>
>   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
>   StreamReader info = new StreamReader("Structure.txt");
> ```

because the argument `filePath` is also `"Structure.txt"`. Why open the same file more than once for the same operation?

---

`StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` implement `IDisposable` and should be disposed off like:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("helle.cs"))
{
   ...
}
```

---

You shouldn't hardcode string literals in a method but provide them as arguments:

```
public static void WriteToFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
   ...
}
```

---

Instead of:

> ```
>  while (!reader.EndOfStream)
>  {
>
>     temp = reader.ReadLine();
> ```

it is better to do:

```
string line = null;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   ...
}
```

---

> `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Hello.cs", true);`

you set the `append` argument to true, but I'm quite sure you mean to overwrite the existing file?

---

Comment: This is a giant bug you've spotted there +1! I'll VTC the question.